# Typo3 subscribe to newsletter

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I want to add a "subscribe to newsletter" field to my website, which gives me then a list of emails in the backend. Unfortunately all the plugins I have found so far either send you emails directly from the backend or are very complicated to set up.

So is there an easy extension that just gives me an element with a textfield and a button (to subscribe) which I can then put on my landing page that just saves all the emails in the backend?

Answer (score 2):

You can use e.g. powermail. Yes it is a bit more complicated but you need to follow GDPR and this means you also need double opt in!